# How can I make position:fixed work on iOS 7?

Tags: html, iphone, ios, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I've created a test webpage demonstrating `position:fixed` issue on `UIWebView` and Mobile Safari:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="overflow: hidden; ">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.2, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Test</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    } 
    .fullscreen {
      background: transparent;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0; left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .screen {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      /*-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
      -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;*/
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="screen" id="screen"></div>
  <form><textarea id="code" name="code" class="fullscreen" rows="1">
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
  </textarea></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open the demo webpage on Mobile Safari on iPad or iPhone.
2. Tap on the textarea to show a keyboard.
3. Scroll up or down to see the issue.

The inset shadow should be along the edges of the browser window, but it's incorrectly positioned further down the page.

[image]

How can I make `position:fixed` work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not answer to the original question but it's a solution with the same result. Change body's style to the following:

```
.body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;

  /*-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;*/
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;

  min-height: 100%;
}
```

`screen` element may be removed.

Comment: I think `.fullScreen` is the textarea: `<textarea id="code" name="code" class="fullscreen" rows="1">`

Comment: Sorry, I've wrote the answer based on corrected code. I've fixed it.

Comment: where is `.fullScreen` applied to `body`? I can't see that in the code posted in the question.

Comment: Also I've added a note that it's not answer but it's a solution.